# how to display dynamic in requirefield validator in dynamic html table.

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlcontrols

following code shows the error..

```
req.Display = "dynamic"; 
cell.Controls.Add(req);
```

It shows the error. how to display dynamic ?

Comment: which programming language you're using?

Comment: C#. .it is solved now. .it's  rq.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;

Answer (score 1):

You must use the enum available for the Validator.

```
req.Display=ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
```

Think this will help you.